# JSF tagattribute.getBoolean() throws null pointer exception in Tomcat 8.0.39

Tags: jsf, tomcat8, myfaces

When the xhtml page is rendered I get below exception. This works fine in Tomcat 8.0.20 and after Tomcat upgrade to 8.0.39 this exception occurs. Kindly help! We are using a custom taglibs which in turn uses jsf core libs. q:column tag has a attribute named fieldName, when the value of fieldName is empty page renders fine but if there is some value assigned to fieldName null pointer exception is thrown.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:229)
qcom.cas.security.utils.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:25)
qcom.cas.security.utils.IE9CompatablityFilter.doFilter(IE9CompatablityFilter.java:27)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:141)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:281)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
qcom.cas.security.bean.admin.SecurityAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SecurityAuthenticationFilter.java:276)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:341)
```

Root cause

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.sun.facelets.tag.TagAttribute.getBoolean(TagAttribute.java:45)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseWhenHandler.isTestTrue(ChooseWhenHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:67)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseWhenHandler.apply(ChooseWhenHandler.java:45)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseOtherwiseHandler.apply(ChooseOtherwiseHandler.java:41)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:73)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.IfHandler.apply(IfHandler.java:54)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:119)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:241)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:98)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:122)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:122)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:122)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:64)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:131)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseWhenHandler.apply(ChooseWhenHandler.java:45)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:119)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:144)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:241)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:98)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:64)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:131)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseOtherwiseHandler.apply(ChooseOtherwiseHandler.java:41)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:73)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:119)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:144)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:241)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:98)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:64)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:131)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseWhenHandler.apply(ChooseWhenHandler.java:45)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ChooseHandler.apply(ChooseHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:119)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:144)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:241)
com.sun.facelets.tag.UserTagHandler.apply(UserTagHandler.java:98)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:64)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:131)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:310)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:280)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.tag.jstl.core.IfHandler.apply(IfHandler.java:54)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:144)
com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:95)
com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:524)
com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:108)
org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:216)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:115)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
qcom.cas.security.utils.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:25)
qcom.cas.security.utils.IE9CompatablityFilter.doFilter(IE9CompatablityFilter.java:27)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:141)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:281)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
qcom.cas.security.bean.admin.SecurityAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SecurityAuthenticationFilter.java:276)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:341)
```

Comment: Hi, see [ask]  on providing code for things that are not working. Also see [mcve]